# TPL Dataflow, Exception in block fault handler does not propagate

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm using a TPL dataflow block to process a stream of messages. My data flow network is composed of two blocks, a BufferBlock and an ActionBlock, with the action block being defined as:

```
        _actionBlock = new ActionBlock<Func<Task>>((Action<Func<Task>>) ProcessRequest,
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
            });
```

If an error occurs inside the action block, I want to let the fault propagate up and exit the application. Later on I'm planning to add in logic here to handle transient errors, but for now, any errors should cause the application to exit with the fault details. To this end, I've added a ContinueWith section like this:

```
        _actionBlock
            .Completion
            .ContinueWith(dbt =>
                {
                    var inner = dbt.Exception.InnerExceptions.First();
                    throw inner;
                },
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted
            );
```

The problem is that the "throw inner" doesn't propagate up to anywhere, the application just carries on as if the exception was being swallowed. I don't have any further exception handlers in my code. As an experiment I've tried

- Re-throwing the exception using

  ```
     Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => throw ...)
  ```
- Checking that the ContinueWith contents are running on the UI thread.
- Handling any top level exceptions using:

  ```
  currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(ToplevelHandler);
  ```

(The exception thrown never reaches TopLevelHandler)

None of these has helped.

How can I make the exception that I throw inside the ContinueWith function propagate to the top of the application and make the application exit with an error message?

Comment: When you `throw inner` you'll need to `await` that `Task` at some point to propagate the exception.

Comment: _actionBlock is long running though. I create it on application startup and under the normal course of things it keeps running for the length of the application. There's isn't a natural point in the code where I could await it's Completion task without blocking everything.

Comment: Unfortunately that's where the exception winds up. But in that event the `ActionBlock` is faulted and wouldn't continue processing anyway. You can  handle exceptions within the flow or attach them to the result of the flow for handling outside.

Comment: @James ActionBlocks are always long running. If you want to handle exceptions after the block completes, though a fault or normal completion, you `await` it. `ContinueWith` will only run when that ActionBlock *completes* anyway.

Comment: @James as for the exception not propagating, you wrote the equivalent of `TaskFactory.StartNew(()=>throw new Exception());`. If you don't await that task, the exception will disappear. Where *do* you want that error to appear anyway?

Comment: I'll try and edit the question to add some more context - in brief what I want to happen is that if a exception occurs inside the action block the application should end, unless the exception is transient, in which case, I will handle it (show the user a disconnected warning and retry after a timeout).

Answer (score 4):

Quote from Concurrency in C# Cookbook (Stephen Cleary):

> To catch exceptions from a Dataflow block, await its Completion
>   property. The Completion property returns a Task that will complete
>   when the block is completed, and if the block faults, the Completion task is also faulted.

```
actionBlock = new ActionBlock<Func<Task>>((Action<Func<Task>>) ProcessRequest,
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
    });
await actionBlock.Completion;
```